# how to have multiple if statements in Haskell?

Tags: if-statement, haskell

like consider the following python code,

```
n = 4
if n>3 :
  n = 5
if n>2 :
  n = 6
if n>1 :
  n = 4
```

How to achieve this in haskell??

```
let n = 4
main :: IO()
main = do 
    if n>3 then let n = 5
    if n>2 then let n = 6
    if n>1 then let n = 4
```

Tried this but gives an error, looking for some modifications

Comment: `if` staments must be followed by `else`. Therefore you should write `if n>3 then ... else if n>4 then ... else ...`. A more idiomatic way would be using [guards](https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/functional-programming-haskell/0/steps/27226). Also notice than Haskell in inmutable, therefore  you program is not changing the value of `n` which looks like you intention. My recommendation, define a function `f :: Int -> Int` which uses guards to branch cases and returns the desire value.

Comment: It's kinda a silly example program, too, because it's the same as `if n > 1 then n = 4`.

Comment: You cannot have multiple if statements, or even a single if statement, in Haskell. There is no such thing in this language. There is an `if` *expression*. Expressions do not have side effects. `let` is an expression too, and not a statement, and it doesn't work like assignment in other languages works.

Comment: Well, `let` without an `in` is a sort of quasi-statement inside a `do` block, but `do` blocks are really a kind of DSL that gets translated into regular Haskell expressions. In particular, `do let x = y; ...` is equivalent to `let x = y in do ...`.  `do` blocks are a syntactic convenience; it's possible to write any Haskell program without using `do` at all.

Comment: `do` also is *specifically* for writing code using a particular monad; it's not just some sort of imperative-style "escape hatch". The closest thing to an `if`-sans-`else` in Haskell is the `when` function, which lets you write `when (n > 3) foo`. (But `foo` has to be a value of type `Applicative f => f ()`.)

Answer (score 2):

While the example is a bit contrived, the usual way to encode an if with multiple branches is to use a case-of with `()` as the scrutinee as follows:

```hs
main :: IO()
main = do 
    case () of 
             _ | n > 3 -> ...
               | n > 2 -> ...
               | otherwise -> ...
```

or when part of a binding, by use of a guarded let

```
let x | n > 3 = ...
      | n > 2 = ...
      | otherwise = ...
```

Alternatively, this may also be encoded as guards of a helper function

```hs
f :: Int -> Int
f n | n > 3 = 5
    | n > 2 = 6
    | otherwise = 4
```

Updated to include [@Iceland_jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165806/iceland-jack)'s comment

Comment: There is no need to `case () of ..` anymore, we have [multi-way `if`-expressions](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/multiway_if.html) but most of the time it can be written as guards `let x | x > 3 = 5 | x > 2 = 6 ..`.

Comment: I am reluctant to enable or recommend syntactical extensions like `MultiWayIf`, but a guarded-let is probably better indeed for the original question.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented there are some points of your program you should checkout

- `else` *must* be used after if
- You don't use `let` for top level declarations (as in `let n = 4`).
- When you write `if n>3 then let n=5` you are not changing the value of `n` because values are inmutables in Haskell

There are a few "idiomatic" ways you can rewrite your program

Use a chained `if then else` with `print`s. This is the closest to your code

```hs
n = 4 -- no let in top level binding

main :: IO()
main = do  
    if n>3 then print 5  -- do not use let n=5 because n can't be mutated
      else if n>2 then print 6 
        else if n>1 then print 4 
          else print ()
```

Use an external function and guards. This is the most idiomatic

```hs
f :: Int -> Int
f x | x > 3 = 5
    | x > 2 = 6
    | x > 1 = 4

n = 4
main = do
  print (f n)
```

As @davidflecher commented, you can use guards within a let binding

```hs
n = 4

main :: IO()
main = do 
  let x | n > 3 = 5
        | n > 2 = 6
        | n > 1 = 4
  print x
```

Use `MultyWayIf` extension (This is more advance as it needs extensions to the language)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

n = 4

main :: IO()
main = do 
  let x = if | n > 3 -> 5
             | n > 2 -> 6
             | n > 1 -> 4
  print x
```

Comment: MultiWayIf is not needed here, you can already use guards in a let.  Just write `let x | n > 3 = 5`.

Comment: @DavidFletcher I knew this could be done!!! I was writing `let x | n > 3 -> 5` and ghc was complaining about parse error in `->`; that's how I came out with `MultiWaIf`...